# how to copy hyperlinks to emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to copy a text with hyperlink from external files (e.g., word(.doc) file) to Emacs with hyperlink preserved? it could be very annoying if I copy an articles with 100 hyperlinks from word to Emacs and have to re-input each hyperlink

Such function seems to be unavailable from the vanilla Emacs, and I am pretty new to Emacs, so I wish somebody here can come up with a simple function to enable that.

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "reserved", given an example please (before and after) what went wrong.

Comment: To those who aren't understanding this: he had some text in MS WORD (or something) and the text had a *hidden* hyperlink. As in, the text is blue and clickable and takes you to the url. He wants to copy that text into emacs without losing the hyperlinks (which is the default behavior), That's what he means by "preserve".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the hyperlink to work (meaning the actual hyperlink is hidden and the word "here" is emphasized/highlighted and is "clickable" by either mouse or keyboard shortcut and/or <kbd>M-x</kbd> function call) in emacs you need to use one of the modes which support such a behavior:

- [Org mode](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Hyperlinks) which is a major mode and a very substantial package with a ton of functionality. Create a file with `.org` extension, copy the link's url there and it becomes "live". You can edit it to hide the url by clicking <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-l</kbd> while your cursor is on the link, then confirm the url and add description - the "here" word. After that the url becomes hidden and "here" becomes highlighted and clickable.
- One of the [Wiki modes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsWikiMode), there are both major and minor modes (so you can try using the functionality in files having various major modes). Please consult the link for details.

If you would rather not use additional packages, [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html) is the documentation on how to make arbitrary text clickable but you would need to be comfortable with some elisp programming.

UPDATE:

I see that you need the bulk import of urs to emacs. The problem is with incomplete support of the multi-format clipboard content (which is created, for instance, when you copying from a web browser) in emacs. According to http://www.mail-archive.com/help-emacs-windows@gnu.org/msg03026.html there is no support for HTML content so it gets pasted to emacs as plain text. The only way I see is to open the page source in the browser, save it to file, extract list of urls (and surrounding text if you needed it) using xsltproc or whatever and convert the urls to org-mode style links (also with xsltproc or emacs regex search/replace). Unfortunately there is no html-to-org converter that I know of.

Comment: well, actually I want to copy text with hyperlink from external program to emacs with hyperlink reserved. I know how to add hyperlink in org-mode, but it could be very annoying if i copy an articles with 100 hyperlinks to Emacs and have to re-input each hyperlink...

Answer (score 0):

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html should do the job.
And it's able to do a lot more.

Comment: You'd have to elaborate more on your use case.
What are you trying to do, actually?
I was assuming implicitly that you were using `org-mode`.
But if you're looking for something more simple,
`browse-url-at-point` works for all modes.