# org-protocol formatting selected text

Tags: css, emacs, org-mode

When you capture through org-protocol and a browser, either through the `capture();` function or `encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection());`, the text appears to be passed to the Emacs org-protocol server as plain text.

Is there a way to pull in some of the HTML heading/CSS style info to keep a minimal amount of formatting for readability? Most sites aren't anything close to plain text, so even selecting across a heading and a couple paragraphs comes out like garbage.

edit: I found [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/), which will do HTML to org-mode conversions, but the results are [overkill](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/?text=%3Chead%3E%0A%09%09%3Ctitle%3EWhatsMyIP.org+|+Buy+Pixel+Ads%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%09%09%3Cmeta+charset%3D%22utf-8%22%3E%0A%09%09%3Cmeta+name%3D%22keywords%22+content%3D%22whatsmyip+whats+my+ip+address+buy+pixels+pixel+advertising%22%3E%0A%09%09%3Cmeta+name+%3D%22description%22+content%3D%22WhatsMyIP+Pixel+Ads!+Buy+Pixels+to+advertise+your+website.+%241.00+per+pixel.%22%3E%0A%09%09%3Clink+type%3D%22application%2Frss%2Bxml%22+rel%3D%22alternate%22+title%3D%22WhatsMyIP.org+RSS+Feed%22+href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Frss.whatsmyip.org%2Fwhatsmyip.php%22%3E%0A%09%09%3Clink+href%3D%22..%2Fstyle.css%22+type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22+rel%3D%22stylesheet%22%3E%0A%09%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%0A%09%3Cbody%3E%0A%09%09%3Ctable+class%3D%22layout%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Ctr%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3Ctd+colspan%3D%222%22+class%3D%22cell%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%3Ctable+class%3D%27header_box%27%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%3Ctr%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%3Ctd%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%3Cdiv+class%3D%22title%22%3EWhatsMyIP+PixelAds%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%3Ctd%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%241+Per+Pixel%3Cbr%3E10+x+10+Pixel+Blocks%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%3Ctd%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%24100+Per+Block%3Cbr%3ELasts+Forever!%2a%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%3Ctd%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%099%2C968+Blocks+Available%3Cbr%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%28996%2C800+Pixels%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%09%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%09%3C%2Ftr%3E&from=html&to=org). Is there any way to get just the formatting from the selected objects, not a blind parse of HTML chunk?

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17624996/973603 help?

Comment: Yeah, is that still current re: the lack of HTML-to-org support?

Comment: Yes, I think that is still the case. Instead of org-protocol you can try using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) (that's what I do) and use its language to copy the selected html to clipboard and clean it up prior to inserting into org-capture buffer.

Comment: I guess it's simplest to copy-paste into the buffer after clicking the the bookmarklet with no selection...