# paste HTML into org-mode as org-mode markup?

Tags: html, emacs, markdown, clipboard, org-mode

Is there a tool that will allow me to copy content from a web site (images, headings, links, and paragraph text) and paste that content into org-mode in proper org-mode markup (e.g. with the links and image URLs denoted in org-mode syntax) without going through the extra step of converting the HTML file separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168926/org-protocol-formatting-selected-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(defun kdm/html2org-clipboard ()
  "Convert clipboard contents from HTML to Org and then paste (yank)."
  (interactive)
  (setq cmd "osascript -e 'the clipboard as \"HTML\"' | perl -ne 'print chr foreach unpack(\"C*\",pack(\"H*\",substr($_,11,-3)))' | pandoc -f html -t json | pandoc -f json -t org")
  (kill-new (shell-command-to-string cmd))
  (yank))
```

Source: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12121/org-mode-parsing-rich-html-directly-when-pasting

Comment: To prevent line wrapping in the pasted text, add `--wrap=none` to the pandoc option so the command becomes `osascript -e 'the clipboard as \"HTML\"' | perl -ne 'print chr foreach unpack(\"C*\",pack(\"H*\",substr($_,11,-3)))' | pandoc -f html -t json | pandoc -f json -t org --wrap=none`

Answer (score 2):

It seems [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html) can do the job. It can read several structured markup languages and export to [org mode](http://uce.uniovi.es/tips/Emacs/OrgPandoc.html).

Comment: But not through a simple copy and paste operation.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an add-on [Copy as Org-Mode](https://github.com/kuanyui/copy-as-org-mode) for Firefox which can do this in browser directly, it even can convert HTML tables into Org-mode format.
[image]